# Conflict between Isotope filtering and Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jquery-isotope

I have a Fancybox gallery that is filtered using jQuery Isotope. My problem is that even when filtered, Fancybox still cycles through all of the images. I know this issue has a few discussions here and have tried all of the solutions on those pages without success.

I’m wondering if anyone can spot a conflict, probably in my filter script. I’m using Isotope v1.5.25.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
<!-- Filter -->
<nav id="options" class="work-nav">
<ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
<li class="type-work">Type of Work</li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">All Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".branding">Branding</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".brochure">Brochure</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<!-- End Filter -->
</div>

<div class="span12">
<div class="row">
<section id="projects">
<ul id="thumbs">

<li class="item-thumbs span3 branding">
<a class="hover-wrap fancybox1" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Image Title" href="bigImage.jpg ">
<span class="overlay-img"></span>
<span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-search"></span>
</a>
<img src="thumb.jpg" alt="">
```

ISOTOPE SCRIPT

```
DK.filter = function (){
if($('#projects').length > 0){      
var $container = $('#projects');

$container.imagesLoaded(function() {
$container.isotope({

// options

animationEngine: 'best-available',
itemSelector : '.item-thumbs',
layoutMode : 'fitRows'
});
});

// open filtered items only

$('#filters a').click(function(){
var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$('#projects').isotope({ filter: selector }, function(){
if(selector == "*"){
$(".fancybox1").attr("data-fancybox-group", "gallery");
} else{ 
$(selector).find(".fancybox1").attr("data-fancybox-group", selector);
}
});
return false;
});

// filter items when filter link is clicked

var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
$optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

$optionLinks.click(function(){
var $this = $(this);

// don't proceed if already selected

if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
return false;
}
var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
$optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$this.addClass('selected');

// make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
var options = {},
key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
// parse 'false' as false boolean
value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
options[ key ] = value;
if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {

// changes in layout modes need extra logic

changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
} else {
// otherwise, apply new options
$container.isotope( options );
}

return false;
});
}
}
```

UPDATE: I've managed to get the filtering to work correctly and have updated the script above. The issue was using the `data-option-value` attribute instead of the `data-filter` one and referencing `$('#isotopegallery').isotope({ filter: selector }, function(){` instead of `$('#projects').isotope({ filter: selector }, function(){`.

The problem now is when I click on the first filtered item, in this case 'branding' nothing happens. Then thumbnails only filter once I click on the page a second time.

Can anyone please shed some light on this????

Comment: `var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');` ... I don't see any `data-filter` attribute in your html; am I missing something?

Comment: @JFK you are correct there is no 'data-filter' attribute in the HTML as far as I can see. The template I'm using applies the 'data-option-value' attibute instead I think. I tried 'var selector = $(this).attr('data-option-filter');' and that didn't work. I may have to re-do the isotope HTML and use the data-filter attribute.